# At what point do breakpoints pause execution in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints

quick question about breakpoints. does the breakpoint execute the line of code on which it was placed and then break before the next line is executed? or does it break before the line on which it was placed is executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Breakpoints break before executing the line on which they are placed.

For example, if you run the following program and place the breakpoint on the second line

```
int x = 5, y = 10;
x += y; // <<== Breakpoint here
```

when breakpoint is hit, `x` is still five, not fifteen. You can check the value of the variable in the debugger:

[image]

Comment: But it needs to be noted that any sort of optimization will muck this up, and even in supposedly unoptimized code it's not 100% reliable.  And the variable display in the debugger is even less reliable -- better to use `p` and `po` in the console window than to trust the debugger variable display.

Comment: this answer gets the win. thanks for the details and pictures, very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Before.

It took you more time to write the question, than to try yourself, by the way.

Comment: i did check myself. i thought it would be a useful question for stackoverflow though